# Login Screen goes blank after being idle

Tags: login, screen

When I boot Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 and get to the login screen if I leave it idle for a minute or two the screen goes blank.  How can I disable that?  I've already tried disabling everything in Power and Privacy via the GUI and I've tried gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
and gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
but nothing is working.

Thanks

InNeedOfHelp

Comment: Many of the GNOME settings only apply when GNOME is properly running (ie. you're logged in; before that point user settings for a user haven't actually applied anyway as no-one is logged in). Before login you're limited to whatever settings are available on your *display manager* (ie. greeter settings). The default is GDM3 for Ubuntu Desktop installs